asp.net core compression different behavior between win11 and docker container
when we run our asp.net core (REST) server application in the development environment (Win11, Visual Studio 2022) with activated compression the data the server returns are compressed. When I run the same application in a docker container they aren't.
What is the reason for that behavior and what can we do to reach the compression here too?
Server:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
   services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
   {
      options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
      options.EnableForHttps = true;
   });

   services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
   {
      options.Level = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Fastest;
   });
...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,...)
{
...
   app.UseResponseCompression();
...
}

Client:
headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");


Please show some codes, ideally a full [mre].

Please check if the Accept-Encoding  http header is passed correctly?
